# restrict access to the second form page

Tags: php, html, forms, session-variables

Helloo, I have a mutistep form functionality where 
in "Step1" ( page 1 ) i have a form with three radioButton

And in step 2 (page2 ) I have another form.
So, My problem is that I want to restrict access to page2 via URL like if I type in Browser Addressbar : localhost/page1.php then it should load page1.php  but when I write localhost/page2.php then it should restrict user to have access for page2  and I would like to be redirected to localhost/page1.php

so i tried this :

page1 :

```
  <form class="type" action="page2.php" method="post">
   <label style="text-align:center;"> Type de compte :  </label>
                </br> </br>
   <input  type="radio" name="typeCompte" value="enseig"  required> 
                 Enseignant </br>
   <input type="radio" name="typeCompte" value="etud" required> 
                  Etudiant </br>
   <input type="radio"  name="typeCompte" value="admin" required> 
                  Adminstrateur </br>
    </br></br>
   <input type="submit" class="make" name="submit" value="Valider">
   </form>

   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       $_SESSION['log']=1;
    }
   ?>
```

page 2 :

```
 <?php 
      session_start();
      if($_SESSION['log']!=1)
          header("location: page1.php");//redirecting to first page
 ?>
```

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

Comment: Put a simple condition on your first PHP page and check the conditions that are fulfilled, if not filled then just use the PHP redirect to the page you want. Seems like you haven't R&D before coming to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting session variable as bool like...

In **Page1.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_POST['submit']){
        $_SESSION['log'] = "true";
         header("Location: page2.php");
  }
  ?>
```

Then In **Page2.php**

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log'] == "false"){
     //send them back
     header("Location: page1.php");
  }
 else{
     //your logic if any.
  }
```

I think in Php session might be working on true false basis only..

Comment: when i try this when i'm in page1.php i can access to page 2 when i type localhost/page2.php

Comment: because your session value might be set in browser so try restarting browser and then directly type page2.php in browser . And don't forget to put session checking logic on top of your page.

Comment: same problem :/

Comment: but in page1 $_SESSION['log'] = "true"; must be in if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: i just try with true and false i have the same problem i can access to page 2 via URL + Notice: Undefined index: log in page2

Comment: why make header("Location: page2.php"); in page1 i already have action's form page2.php

Comment: i can acces to page2 with a  Notice : Undefined index: log in

Comment: i don't understand why It's seems logical :(

Comment: @kahinakahina you need to look at his answer in code form and if you don't understand it then research it

Comment: if it doesn't work then it means you have a problem somewhere else this code same as my answer must work

Comment: it means you don't have session_start(); on both page

Comment: see i try the same thing and i still have same problem

Answer (score 1):

to check for session you can use isset command

```
<?php session_start();

//if ! means not isset check if the session is active
if(!isset($_SESSION['log']))
header("location:page1.php");
?>
```

in your page where you assign the session for log you can use it to assign any value for the user that you might need later. however do some reading about .htaccess and put your limited access file in a different dir
 on page 1

```
$t='1';
$_SESSION['log']=$t;
```

and very very important on the first line after `<?php` on page 1 you must have

```
session_start();
```

edit try this that i wrote only spend 5 min so it is not much but i tested it and it works make 2 file test1.php and test2.php
test1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['set'])){
    $log='1';
    $_session['log']=$log;
    include_once("test2.php");
    exit;
    }
if(isset($_POST['dontset'])){
    include_once("test2.php");
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">      
            <input type="submit" name="set" value="set">
            <input type="submit" name="dontset" value="dontset">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
    if (!isset($_session['log'])){
        echo 'you are not authorised';
        header("location:test1.php");
    }
    if (isset($_session['log'])){
        echo 'you are authorised';
        }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">      
            <input type="submit" name="destroy" value="destroy">
        </form>
    </body>
</html> 
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['destroy'])){
        session_destroy();
            include_once("test2.php");
        exit;
    }


?>
```

it also shows you how to logout the user using sessions

Comment: when i try this it work i can't access to page2 via URL but even when i click on submit i'm redirected to page1 not to page2

Comment: same problem ( can't even access to page2 when i click on submit)

Comment: try the example i wrote and implement it like that in the same format and take note where is my php and where is my html